# Youtube api V3 get video resolution

Tags: youtube-api, dimensions, aspect-ratio

Some videos come with letterbox / pillarbox black frames like these for example:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pSZofb3VKGU

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=glGjB3nTmqw

compared to full size video 16/9:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_ZAZD3ylG6Y

I wanted to get video resolution from youtube using their api, but after some investigating I think I am out of luck because I need fileDetails part from Youtube which can only be retrieved by video owner.

Can anybody think of another way to detect video comes in letterbox / pillarbox frame and detect dimensions? ( so I can scale the video myself when embedding, thus removing black borders )

Answer (score 1):

[Reference](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/revision_history#november-2-2016)

> By default, the height of the  returned in the
>   player.embedHtml property is 360px. The width adjusts to match the
>   video's aspect ratio, thereby ensuring that the embedded player does
>   not have black bars framing the video. So, for example, if a video's
>   aspect ratio is 16:9, the player's width would be 640px.

You have to user `player` part when retrieving video. For example

Following request

```
GET https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?part=player&id=pSZofb3VKGUkey={YOUR_API_KEY}
```

will give you following response. Once you embed this video you can see the black border is not there.

```
"player":{
    "embedHtml":"\u003ciframe width=\"480\" height=\"360\"    src=\"//www.youtube.com/embed/pSZofb3VKGU\" frameborder=\"0\"  allowfullscreen\u003e\u003c/iframe\u003e"
}
```

This is not working with the video id `glGjB3nTmqw` may be Youtube is not scaling the height I guess, not sure.

My opinion you don't need to worry about the dimensions. You use the `player` to get the embed html & render it. Youtube will do all the work of removing the black bars.

Comment: I know embedding size because I am embedding videos, and I use youtube api to retrieve video list or videos from playlist etc. then when I load the video in the player, I need to know resolution if I want to get rid of such cases with black bars (because this is what I want). This doesnt help me unfortunately.